# I want to call two IDs with one anchor tag, one in the right sidebar and one in iframe (both IDs are same)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to call two IDs with one anchor tag, one in the right sidebar and one in iframe (both IDs are same). onclick functions can also try. I have tried with same ids but its not working.

My requirement.

1. when I click link from left sidebar, ID should be called in right sidebar and iframe.

please note: ids are same with iframe.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
    $('.nav ul li a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(content).show();
        $(content).siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
*,
.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Author", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
.bg-dark,
.btn-dark {
  background: #0d1117 !important;
}
.nav .btn {
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20252c !important;
}
.border-end {
  border-right: 1px solid #20252c !important;
}
.border-start {
  border-left: 1px solid #20252c !important;
}
.publish-btn {
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 95%;
}
.icon-sm {
  width: 1.4em;
}
.icon-xs {
  width: 1em;
}
.nav .btn-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav .bg-success {
  background-color: #1987545e !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.nav a {
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
}
#iframe {
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.iframe {
  border: 2px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.vh-100 {
  height: 93.5vh !important;
}
.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-control {
  background: #12171f !important;
  border: 1px solid #20252c !important;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  color: white !important;
}
dl,
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link href="https://udee.space/db2/db/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row vh-100 bg-dark">
  <div class="col-2 border-end px-4 p-2 pt-5 text-white">
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#section-site-identity"
        ><i data-feather="command" class="icon-xs"></i> &nbsp; Logo</a
      >
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#usefulLinks" target="myIframe"
        ><i data-feather="heart" class="icon-xs"></i> &nbsp; Useful link</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8">
<div class="center p-5" id="iframe">
  <div
    class="row text-white"
    style="
      background: rgb(120, 120, 120);
      border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
      border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
    "
  >
    <center>
      <i data-feather="globe" class="icon-xs"></i> domainname.com
    </center>
  </div>
  <iframe
    class="center shadow-lg iframe"
    src="https://udee.space"
    title=""
    name="myIframe"
  ></iframe>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2 border-start px-4 p-2 pt-5 text-white">
<div id="section-active" class="tab-content"><h6>Active div</h6></div>
<div id="section-site-identity" class="tab-content"><h6>logo div</h6></div>
<div id="usefulLinks" class="tab-content"><h6>Useful link</h6></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is "both IDs are same": `id` attributes, _by definition_, must be unique. If you want to select multiple elements using a single query selector, uses classes.

Comment: @mike, if one's in an iframe, that would be fine because it's a different document. But OP's "not working" doesn't tell us anything. I don't see where it's referencing the url ID in the JS, nor where it's trying to do anything in the iframe.

Comment: If it's "the same id, but one in a parent, and one in an iframe" then those are two completely different webpages, loaded on different origins, and anything in the iframe is entirely off limits to the owning page. For very obvious security reasons =)

Comment: Do we know the iframe is a different origin? I guess I'm not sure what "call an ID" is supposed to mean, but if it means to scroll to it, I would guess that using a `#` in its src attribute would do that.

Comment: `ID should be called` please explain, that doesn't mean anything

Comment: `ID should be called` I just want to show the content or that section at a same time, means iframe section should scroll to it and at the same tome right sidebar content should be change

Comment: iframe content is a literally a different webpage, with its own `document`. And one that, for security reasons, you do not have access to (unless it's same-origin and/or you've set the server for the iframe's content to include the appropriate CORS headers).